# How to stop an application?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application and from, In this application I have to start another process by shutting down the current application and after the completion of the process again start the application. The flow is as follows, suppose I have an application *app.exe*, and another application *another.exe*, so I have to do following:

1. Start *app.exe*
2. Stop/shutdown *app.exe* and start *another.exe* from *app.exe*
3. When *another.exe* completes, stop/shutdown *another.exe* and start *app.exe from another.exe*

Anyone please provide me some clue of how to do it?

Comment: And since your question is about starting an application, not about stopping it, perhaps you should reword the title of the question.

Comment: If your concern is that another.exe will start doing stuff before app.exe finishes shutdown, you can make use of global mutexes to prevent this.  If you don't want this to interfere with other instances, you can generate the name of the mutex randomly and pass it to another.exe as a parameter, though passing names of mutexes as commandline parameters feels very wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You need to either make "another.exe" restart "app.exe" before it exits, or have a third program monitor the first two and restart "app.exe" when "another.exe" exits.

So either:

1. "app.exe" starts
2. "app.exe" spawns "another.exe", and then exits
3. "another.exe" starts
4. "another.exe" spawns "app.exe", and then exits

or:

1. "monitor.exe" starts
2. "app.exe" starts
3. "app.exe" exits
4. "monitor.exe" detects that "app.exe" exited, and spawns "another.exe"
5. "another.exe" starts
6. "another.exe" exits
7. "monitor.exe" detects that "another.exe" exited, and spawns "app.exe"

If "app.exe" should still start "another.exe", here's a variant:

1. "app.exe" starts
2. "app.exe" spawns "monitor.exe" and "another.exe", then exits
3. "another.exe" starts
4. "another.exe" exits
5. "monitor.exe" detects that "another.exe" exited, and spawns "app.exe", then exits

Comment: +1 for the monitor.exe. This is very similar to what I was typing when I saw this answer. :-)

Comment: What about if either monitored process dies unexpectedly? How will "monitor.exe" determine that the termination of the process was a failure, and not the expected normal termination? It might be that the alternate process should not start if the prior one hadn't actually completed its' tasks normally - you'd need to build some sort of check into the monitor process to look for a 'good' termination event (e.g. a zero return-code) before starting the other...

Answer (score 1):

Here how to stop current process

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Close();
```

Of course call it once you have started another.exe with

```
Process.Start(...).
```

Comment: AS I Have mentioned 
"Of course call it once you have started another.exe with"...
Please read the answer again ;)

Comment: The current process starts another process and this process stops first process.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your looking for

```
Process.Start("My Process");

            Process processToClose = Process.GetProcessById(your Process ID);
            processToClose.Kill();
```

Remember to include:

```
Using System.Diagnostics;
```

If these dont suit your needs check out the other methods in the Process class, I'm sure something will catch your eye.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a third exe that stops/start your main application. Once app.exe is closed it can't execute anything.

So try the following:

write a applicationSwitcher.exe that helps you to open/close applications and switch to your main application.